# Google Anlaytics Track origin of newly registered users

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

I'm a web developer and pretty new to Google Analytics.

I need to track the origin of new registered users, and i'm a bit confused about how i'm supposed to do this.
Let's say a user come to my site from Facebook, if he creates an account, i should be able to track it show it (somehow) on the Google Anlytics page.

So far i'm using Events, (Using CURL) :

```
    $data = array(
        'v'     => 1,
        'tid'   => $this->container->getParameter('ga.code'),
        'cid'   => uniqid(),
        't'     => 'event'
    );

    $data['ec'] = 'Registration';
    $data['ea'] = 'register';
    $data['el'] = 'success';
    $data['ev'] = 1;

    $contentArray = http_build_query( $data );
    $contentArray = utf8_encode( $contentArray );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array( 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ) );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contentArray );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_exec( $ch);
    curl_close( $ch);
```

This works great, except, the referrer is null.
Looks like as soon as i browse the website, the referer become NULL.

I thought this would be a simple task, with some tutorial or case studies ...
Any help or inputs on how to do it ? 
Thanks.

Comment: do I want to know why you are doing this manually though the measurement protocol and not just using the normal JS snippet on your website?

Comment: Because i want to send an Event when a user just registered. After the registration, the user is redirected to the page where he was before registering, so i need to use an Event.

Comment: And when they hit that page log the event?  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events